# how to delete all from Moor?

Tags: flutter, dart

I tried to delete all when signout.

```
onPressed: () {
       _categoryBloc.deleteEntry();
 }
```

But error is coming

> Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method 'deleteEntry' was
>   called on null. E/flutter ( 9255): Receiver: null E/flutter ( 9255):
>   Tried calling: deleteEntry()

**initial bloc**

```
 CategoryBloc _categoryBloc;
```

**MyBloc class**

```
class CategoryBloc {
...
      void deleteEntry() {
        _categoryRepository.deleteCategory();
      }
...
}
```

**my repo class**

```
deleteCategory() async {
    try{
      await _categoryDao.deleteEntry();
    }catch (e){
      print('Caught in delete ${e.body}');
      rethrow;
    }
  }
```

**dao class**

```
  Future deleteEntry() {
    return delete(categories).delete(Categorie());
  }
```

**data class**

```
class Categorie extends DataClass implements Insertable<Categorie> {
  final String id;
  final bool isActive;
  final String categoryName;
  final int displayOrder;
  Categorie(
      {@required this.id,
      @required this.isActive,
      @required this.categoryName,
      @required this.displayOrder});
  factory Categorie.fromData(Map<String, dynamic> data, GeneratedDatabase db,
.....
```

Comment: Do you every assign `_categoryBloc` and `_categoryDao`? The exception tells you that you're trying to call `deleteEntry` on a null value. This could either be in your widget or you repo class (not sure which since you did not include the stack trace)

Comment: Yeah you probably just forgot to instantiate your bloc

Comment: why question vote down?

Comment: @HannesKüttner I add my own answer. thank you supporting

Comment: @RodrigoBastos I add my own answer. thank you supporting

Answer (score 10, accepted):

changed `onPressed` method like this

```
ProxyProvider<CategoriesRepository,CategoryBloc>(
          builder: (context, categoryRepo, categoryBloc)=>
              CategoryBloc(categoryRepository: categoryRepo),
          dispose: (context, categoryBloc)=> categoryBloc.dispose(),
          ).didChangeDependencies(context, _categoryBloc).deleteEntry();
```

and also If you want to delete all you need to check query like this:

```
  deleteEntry() {
    try{
      return delete(subCategories).go();//like this
    }catch (e){
      print("error is $e");
    }
  }
```